# Doubt in problem related to uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Find the largest positive real number of $\delta $ such that $|\cos x - \cos y | < \sqrt 2$ whenever $|x-y| < \delta?$

a) $\sqrt 2$

b) $3/2$

c) $\pi/2$

d) $2$

My approach: $|\cos x - \cos y| =|-2 \sin\frac{x-y}{2}\sin\frac{x+y}{2}|<\sqrt 2$

$$ \implies |-2 \sin\frac{x-y}{2}\sin\frac{x+y}{2}| \leq|x-y|< \epsilon (=\delta)=\sqrt 2$$
as $|\sin x| \leq |x| \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

So, $\epsilon=\delta = \sqrt 2 $ is one obvious possibility. but it is not the maximum.

I got stuck on how to reach the correct answer from here please give guidance.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Intuitively $\pi/2$ seems the answer. You can show it works by taking $x = \pi/2 + y$ and to see it's maximum note that as you go from $\pi/4$ to $3\pi/4$ $\cos\theta$ goes from $1/\sqrt{2}$ to $-1/\sqrt{2}$ making the difference $\sqrt{2}$. If you take $x$ and $y$ further apart on either side of these values then the difference in their cosine values will exceed $\sqrt{2}$.